# Duplicating a JPanel - (Copy JPanel's static image to different JPanel)

Tags: java, swing, clone

I'm pretty new to swing and I would like to receive some help as Im stuck with a task.

**Current state:**

Im having a nice `JFrame` object (guiFrame) which is having two `JPanel` on it (tabsPanel and cardPanel)(one is a simple `JPanel` with buttons, the other has `CardLayout` which is switched by the tabsPanel buttons).

**Problem:**

The task is that if I press the button "Show" on tabsPanel I need to send the cardPanel to a different window (ShowFrame) as a static "image", while on the previous window the program is still running and nice. So basicly Im trying to copy / clone the cardPanel.

**What I have tried:**

- I have tried to simply

  ```
  JPanel jPanelShow = cardPanel; 
  show.add(jPanelShow);
  ```

  Of course not working because the reference number is being copied and if I run the program, the cardPanel "disappears".
- I have tried to use `clone()`
  For this its almost working but I'm getting some weird `NullPointerException` which isn't caused by my code.

**Current codes (cloning try):**

CardPanel.java

```
/**
 * This is basicly a JPanel, just with a clone() implemented
 */
package javaapplication5;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Stack;

public class CardPanel extends JPanel implements Cloneable {

    public CardPanel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public CardPanel clone() throws NullPointerException {
        /* Creating return object */
        final CardPanel copy;

        try {

            /* Cloning */
            copy = (CardPanel) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {

            /* Exception (should not happen though) */
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

CardLayoutExample.java

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class CardLayoutExample {


    JFrame guiFrame;
    CardLayout cards;
    CardPanel cardPanel;
    private int showFrameNotShownYet = 1;
    public ShowFrame show = new ShowFrame();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         /* Random things for Swing */
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
         {            
            @Override
             public void run()
             {     
                 new CardLayoutExample();         
             }
         });

    }

    public CardLayoutExample()
    { 
        /* Creating the main JFrame */
        guiFrame = new JFrame();

        /* Making sure the program exits when the frame closes */
        guiFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        guiFrame.setTitle("CardLayout Example");
        guiFrame.setSize(400,300);

        /* This will center the JFrame in the middle of the screen */
        guiFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        guiFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        /* Border for JPanel separation */
        Border outline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);

        /* Creating JButton1 for tabsPanel */
        JButton switchCards1 = new JButton("1");
        switchCards1.setActionCommand("1");
        switchCards1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                cards.show(cardPanel, "TestContent");     
            }
        });

        /* Creating JButton2 for tabsPanel */
        JButton switchCards2 = new JButton("2");
        switchCards2.setActionCommand("2");
        switchCards2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                cards.show(cardPanel, "TestContent1");      
            }
        });

        /* Creating JButton3 for tabsPanel */
        JButton switchCards3 = new JButton("3");
        switchCards3.setActionCommand("3");
        switchCards3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                cards.show(cardPanel, "TestContent2");    
            }
        });

        JButton switchCards4 = new JButton("Show");
        switchCards4.setActionCommand("Show");
        switchCards4.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {

                /* If there is no ShowFrame yet */
                if(showFrameNotShownYet == 1){

                    show.add((JPanel)cardPanel.clone());
                    show.setVisible(true);
                    showFrameNotShownYet = 0; 
                } 

                /* If there is a ShowFrame already */
                else {
                    show.setVisible(false);
                    showFrameNotShownYet = 1;
                    guiFrame.repaint();
                }   
            }
        });

        JButton switchCards5 = new JButton("Refresh");
        switchCards5.setActionCommand("Refresh");
        switchCards5.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {                    
                    show.setVisible(false);
                    show.add((JPanel)cardPanel.clone());
                    show.setVisible(true);
                    showFrameNotShownYet = 0;
            }
        });

        /* Creating JPanel for buttons */
        JPanel tabsPanel = new JPanel();
        tabsPanel.setBorder(outline);
        tabsPanel.add(switchCards1);
        tabsPanel.add(switchCards2);
        tabsPanel.add(switchCards3);
        tabsPanel.add(switchCards4);
        tabsPanel.add(switchCards5);

        /* Creating JPanel for CardLayout */
        cards = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new CardPanel();
        cardPanel.setLayout(cards);
        cards.show(cardPanel, "TestContent");

        /* Adding 1st card */
        JPanel firstCard = new TestContent();
        cardPanel.add(firstCard, "TestContent");

        /* Adding 2nd card */
        JPanel secondCard = new TestContent1();
        cardPanel.add(secondCard, "TestContent1");

        /* Adding 3rd card */
        JPanel thirdCard = new TestContent2();
        cardPanel.add(thirdCard, "TestContent2");

        /* Filling up JFrame with stuff */
        guiFrame.add(tabsPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        guiFrame.add(cardPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        guiFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

TestContent, TestContent1 and TestContent2 are simple JPanels with random stuff generated by SwingGUI, just as ShowFrame is empty JFrame. But if needed I will paste in those codes too.

Comment: Never use clone method for swing components. This method is inherited from class Object and if you use it you will get a completly wrong component hierarchy.

Comment: *"The task is that if I press the button "Show" on tabsPanel I need to send the cardPanel to a different window (ShowFrame) as a static "image""*  Why 'static' as opposed to animated?  Why 'clone' it (visually or in any other sense) at all?

Comment: As an aside, this sounds like a complicated task for a seasoned developer.  Beyond the means of a person who is *"pretty new to swing"*.  Perhaps you should work on more (standard) and simpler projects for a while.

Comment: When I press the show button I would like to send the very current state of the cardPanel and Im not willing to update it. Even if I will work on the main window and switch between the cards I still want to show the "previous" state not changing at all on the new showFrame object. Thats what the "Refresh" button will be used for later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need an "image" of the `cardPanel`, you can simply create an image and use a `JLabel` to show, for example...

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(cardPanel.getWidth(), cardPane.getHeight(), BufferedImage.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
cardPanel.printAll(g2d);
g2d.dispose();
```

Now you have a "copy" of the `cardPanel`, you can simply use a `JLabel` to display it, for example...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DIPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thats what Im willing to do as an alternative solution, but if possible I would like to avoid that as this isnt really the "nice way" to solve the problem, its rather a workaround.

Comment: As opposed to trying to clone a UI component, including it's entire component hierarchy and state...okay...

Comment: Well ye, Im not willing to do deep copy either for sure because its beyond my skill level. Looking for a 3rd solution if there is any.

Comment: If you don't require the user to interact with the "clone" in anyway, then creating a snapshot is the simplest solution available to you

Comment: I will probably go for that then. Thank you.