# Cloning JPanel into another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, clone

I want to clone a `JPanel` from `JFrame` **A** to `JFrame` **B**.

I studied http://www.agiledeveloper.com/articles/cloning072002.htm about deep cloning and followed the guide.
However `JFrame` **B** is still blank after `add()`ing cloned `JPanel`

Later on I found a similiar question to mine on [Duplicating a JPanel - (Copy JPanel's static image to different JPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009608/duplicating-a-jpanel), but the answer wasn't what I want because my jpanel involves user interaction which shouldn't be just an image.

Can anyone please give me a hint for this?

### JframeA.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class JframeA extends JFrame {

    private JButton addToSecondFrame;
    private JframeB secondFrame = new JframeB();
    ;
    private SomeJPanelClass myJPanelOri = new SomeJPanelClass();
    private SomeJPanelClass myJPanelClone;

    public JframeA() {
        setTitle("cloning JPanel");
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void run() {

        addToSecondFrame = new JButton("Add to Second Frame");
        addToSecondFrame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                myJPanelClone = (SomeJPanelClass) myJPanelOri.clone();
                secondFrame.getContentPane().add(myJPanelClone);
                secondFrame.validate();
                secondFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

        this.add(myJPanelOri);
        this.add(addToSecondFrame);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JframeA test = new JframeA();
        test.run();
    }

}
```

### JframeB.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JframeB extends JFrame {

    private SomeJPanelClass copiedJPanel;

    public JframeB() {
        setTitle("Frame B");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

### SomeCanvasClass.java

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

public class SomeCanvasClass extends Canvas implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener, KeyListener, Cloneable {


    public SomeCanvasClass() {
        setBackground(Color.red);
        setSize(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
      return super.clone();
  }
}
```

### SomeJPanelClass.java

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class SomeJPanelClass extends JPanel implements Cloneable {

    protected SomeCanvasClass can;

    public SomeJPanelClass(){
        setSize(200,200);
        can = new SomeCanvasClass();
        add(can);
    }

    protected SomeJPanelClass(SomeJPanelClass another){

        SomeCanvasClass ref_can = null;

    try{
        ref_can = (SomeCanvasClass) another.can.clone();

    }
    catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {}

    can = ref_can;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone()  {
        return new SomeJPanelClass(this);
    }
}
```

Edit : added source code

Comment: Provide your code. Currently it sounds like *I have some code which works incorrect. Try to guess why*

Comment: Why should the panel occur in two frames **at the same time?**  I have several projects where I have a rendering component that can either appear in a small window surrounded by configuration controls, or a full screen window without the controls.  That is simply a matter of removing the rendered component from one frame and putting it into a `JWindow` or vice-versa.  That works just fine, since there is just the single instance of the rendered component.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it was actually a **3d model viewer** and i wan it to be able to view side by side **comparing frame A to frame B** from different angle

Comment: *"3d model viewer and .. to be able to view side by side comparing frame A to frame B from different angle"* So have them share the model, but use two separate components.  This ***intensely*** does not feel like a case where one component should be shown/cloned, especially since they are viewing the model from different angles.

Comment: @AndrewThompson by _use two separate components_ , do you mean load the 3d model again for `frame B`?

Comment: *"do you mean load the 3d model again"*  No, it should already be in memory.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i tried to understand but i guess i'm not on that level. can you elaborate ? thanks for your time

Comment: *"i tried to understand but i guess i'm not on that level."*  Be specific about what you don't understand since I'm not in the mood for '20 questions' and don't intend explaining every word I wrote.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it's ok then, i can do my own study. You have been helping me so much, thank you. have a good day :)